# Core Location newLocation can't assign to property

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, geolocation, gps

In Apple's documentation they show this method to use with CoreLocation to pull GPS data

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation     *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
{
}
```

This is to notify you that the GPS has updated. newLocation will have GPS data you need but if I put a statement in this method to assign it to a property noting gets written.

```
latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
NSLog(@"%@", latitude);
```

The NSLog above when put into the method will show the correct coordinates. but it appears the data goes away when the method is over. The property "latitude" in my class doesn't get assigned. Maybe it is a scope problem? I can't return anything from this and I cannot see newLocation outside of the method. Has anyone figured out a way to get around this?

---

EDIT: I am using arc and the latitude property is Strong. Do I need any other attributes?
Here is the implementation code I am using to import the property with. (latitude is a property of LocationAwareness) both these nslogs show null

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "LocationAwareness.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize location;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.location = [[LocationAwareness alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@", location.latitude);
NSLog(@"%@", location.longitude);
}
```

Comment: How do you declare your latitude property?

Comment: @property(strong) NSString *latitude;

Comment: In that case using self.latitude should solve the problem, as I have mentioned in my answer. Also, unless you have very specific reasons no to, you should probably consider declaring your property nonatomic as well.

Comment: You say that latitude is a property of the LocationAwareness object, but you also have seperate latitude property?

Comment: Also, I don't see you synthesizing your latitude property?

Comment: the code above is my view controller. it is synthesized in locationawareness.m

Comment: Are you sure the location has been updated at the time you log the latitude and longitude?

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be retained. Don't forget to release the variable for usage again, and in the dealloc method. Therefore, your -didUpdateToLocation method should look something like the below.

```
latitude = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude] retain];
```

...

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation     *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
{
    if (latitude) {
        [latitude release];
    }

    latitude = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude] retain];
}
```

Otherwise, if you're using ARC just add a property with the 'strong' attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ARC and latitude is a strong property, then use:

```
self.latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
```